# what is RCTTextInlineImage in react native , and how to find this error

Tags: react-native, view

Cannot add a child that doesn't have ha YogaNode to parent without a measure function( trying to add RCTTextInlineImage 773 to RCTView 775]

Comment: I believe this error happens when you're adding an `<Image />` component inside a `<Text />` component. I fumbled around for a while before I figured out that was the cause of my error

Comment: Also I believe `RCTTextInlineImage` is some `android` class or something, but I'm def no expert